# Calculate average score for by category in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Assume I have the following 2 sheets in an Excel workbook:

Sheet `companies`:

```
     A       B       C
1 COMPANY COUNTRY  SCORE
2 Foo     Greece    10
3 Bar     Greece     2
4 Baz     Greece     3
5 Foobar  Japan      8
6 Foobaz  Denmark    6
7 BazBar  Denmark    7
```

Sheet `countries`:

```
     A        B
1 COUNTRY AVG_SCORE
2 Denmark    6.5
3 Greece     5.0
4 Japan      8.0
```

I have calculated the average country score (`AVG_SCORE`) by hand. It is calculated by adding up all country scores and dividing by the number of observations. For instance, Denmark has 2 companies, totally a score of `6` + `7`, which divided by 2 is `6.5`.

Since I have thousands of companies in the first sheet, I need a formula for the cell `countries!B2` (and down) to calculate the average country scores.

Keeping in mind that company data is in a different sheet than the average scores, what formula can calculate the `AVG_SCORES` automatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have Excel 2007+, you can use `AVERAGEIF`. Using your data as a template, you would want to put this in Column B of your `countries` tab:

```
=AVERAGEIF(companies!$B$2:$B$7,"=" & A2,companies!$C$1:$C$7)
```

If you have 2003 or earlier, you can use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((companies!$B$2:$B$7=A2)*companies!$C$2:$C$7)/SUMPRODUCT((companies!$B$2:$B$7=A2)*1)
```

---

EDIT in response to comment:

The `&` is concatenation. i.e. `"a" & "b"` == `"ab"`. In this case, the criteria supplied is a string, so we use the quoted `"="` concatenated with the country we want to look up. The value is in a cell, `A2`, so rather than type it out, we link the `"="` to the cell value with `"=" & A2`, which is the same as `"=Denmark"`.

Comment: This is great. Thanks. What does the `&` mean/do?

Comment: @Pr0no See my update...

Comment: If you want the criterion can be simply A2

Comment: @barryhoudini True (+1 on the comment), but I like to be explicit. In other instances (i.e. dealing with numeric comparisons), I may want to change the `"="` to a `"<"` or `">"`, etc. This helps me remember to keep the proper syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be creating a pivot table, choosing country in the row field and avg as the value field. Then you can link your second sheet to the above created pivot table.